# Contents page of Exoplanets book

Tags: specific-reference, exoplanets

I can't find an online contents page for the book *Exoplanets*, edited by Sara Seager, University of Arizona Press, 2011.

Can you point to such a page, or say what the contents page says?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure that the contents of that exact book are archived online in the format presented on those pages.

However, may I suggest: http://exoplanet.eu/ This is an excellent source for all sorts of exoplanet information.  [They also have a listing of other books](http://exoplanet.eu/biblio-bookThese.php).

If you are really interested in the book itself, then the [University of Arizona does offer it online](http://www.uapress.arizona.edu/Books/bid2263.htm).  (Although, I must admit I am a little puzzled by the description of "cloth" for the book.)

I hope that helps.